# What do they mean by "matrix factorization" in this context.

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for the amateurish question, I didn't want to have to ask here for help but after a long time of trying to figure this out I am still stuck and I need some pointers.

I am trying to implement RLCT synthesis in python following this paper: [Thermal noise compliant synthesis of linear lumped
macromodels](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/76524687.pdf)

But I am stuck at this line:

[image]

I have formed P(I), but I don't know how to factor it into -M M^T,

I know QR and LU decomposition, but those don't seem to fit the bill here, and google searches for "matrix factorization" only seems to bring up unrelated topics.

**Do any of you recognize this type of factorization and can tell me how/where to find a more detailed description of it?.**

A link to a wiki-article or other names for the same thing that I can look up or links to resources describing this are the sorts of things I'm hoping for.

*Or better yet a numpy/scipy function that does it out of the box (wishfull thinking I know).*

Comment: Did you check [17]?

Comment: Hi @Ian, I did look it up and it's a book that I have to buy, which I would really prefer to avoid if I can.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a positive semidefinite matrix, which $-\mathcal{P}(I)$ is in your situation, you can get a factorization in the form $Q \Lambda Q^T$ using either the SVD or diagonalization (both of which can be done for you in numpy). You can write the result as $(Q\Lambda^{1/2}) (Q\Lambda^{1/2})^T$, where $\Lambda^{1/2}$ is just the matrix with the diagonal entries given by the square roots of the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$.

So one $\mathcal{M}$ satisfying the equation is $Q \Lambda^{1/2}$.

Now you can trim $\mathcal{M}$ down by removing rows and columns of zeros from $\Lambda^{1/2}$ along with corresponding columns of $Q$ (the latter being necessary to avoid a domain mismatch of course). I *think* this results in an $\mathcal{M}$ as they are describing in the article.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that inside, that makes sense to me, I will try it out. I was starting to think that cholesky decomposition was what they were refering to..

Comment: @Vinzent You could achieve the same thing with a Cholesky decomposition of $-\mathcal{P}(I)$. However for semidefinite matrices you have to be careful to specify what you mean by a Cholesky decomposition, since just $L L^T=A$ and $L$ lower triangular doesn't specify $L$ uniquely. In particular in standard software you would need to call the routine for the *incomplete* factorization, not the normal routine. For example in Matlab this is "ichol" instead of "chol".

Comment: @Vinzent You are right : Cholesky decomposition is the straightforward tool, more exactly the **incomplete** Cholesky decomposition (in the case of a semidefinite positive matrix).

Comment: Sorry guys I edited the comment about the cholesky decomposition out of my comment before I saw your replies because I thought it was probably nonsense, I have added it back in.

Comment: I will have to try out both of these methods, at least now I have something to go on. Once again thank you very much I am very grateful for you taking your time to give me some guidance.